# Wordpress Plugin for Mockup

Tags: wordpress, image, plugins, generator

Is there any plugin like from front side of website where user can upload their image and it will add into mockup or frame where user can also download this image.

My website is not e-commerce so i no need to use woocommerce plugin for that.

Please suggest.

Comment: Maybe have a look at html2canvas it lets you capture a div to image.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any kind of plugin based on your requirement but alternate solution is like you need to create custom code in functions.php file. here is step that how you can integrate with code.

> 1. First create code where user can upload image from front side.

> 2. Save those image in upload folder and display in mockup using javascript ajax.

> 3. After from frame he/she can save and download image.